# Setting Windows Firewall To Default To "Block All" Bottlenecks Internet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, firefox, thunderbird, windows-firewall

I have been concerned lately with the number of programs that have been transmitting data on my machine, so in attempt to halt all unwanted communication I set the Windows firewall state to block everything inbound and outbound by default.  I then proceeded to add exceptions for IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera (I am a web developer) as well as other programs such as Thunderbird Mail.

One would think this would work, right?  Wrong.  My connection speed always has been about 30Mbps down and 5Mbps up.  After this change I have noticed all communication bottlenecked at 1 to 2 Mbps up and down.  This is also with a significant connection wait time for all established connections.

I returned my settings to original and the problem did not go away.  I may have deactivated a few rules/exceptions in the list that I felt were unnecessary, but when I went through the list and activated groups at a time, none succeeded to fix the bottleneck.  I must also mention that this has effected no other systems on my network, regardless of connection type.  They still operate at the aforementioned ideal speed.

My system specifications:
**Processor:** Intel Core I7 960 Bloomfield (3.2Ghz x4)
**RAM:** 16GB DDR3 (4x 4Gb)
**Network Type:** Wireless N PCIe (Constant five bars) [**NOTE: it says 5.5Mbps as my speed on it now?  WHAT?  Usually well over 100Mbps**]
**OS:** Windows 8 (6.2)
**AV:** Avast! Ver. 2014.9.0.1018

Totally willing to experiment here, I'm sort of desperate!

Comment: 1. You're tilting at windmills. 2. Go into `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security` and click the `Restore Default Policy` link and then click the `Yes` button. This will restore the Windows Firewall to default settings. Then reboot and run your speed test again.

Comment: also worth seeing/you checiing, if this is lan and wlan or just wlan?

Comment: joeqwerty, out of curiosity, would that eliminate all of the exceptions I have made in the past?  
EDIT: Disregard!  I see I can export a policy. Trying now.

Comment: It seems you're right about them windmills... so I guess the real question is what happened while I was configuring the firewall?  Nothing comes to mind, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows firewall settings were changed around the same time that this problem started, which lead me to assume that the firewall was the cause.  I simply checked my connection again the following morning and all was well once again.  I'll leave a comment if I ever discover the true cause.

Comment: It turns out my wireless card was failing, again!  Thankfully I've had luck with this third card for almost a year.